# How do I get the variable name(s) that an object is assigned to in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, objectid

Is there a way to get the variable names currently assigned to the object, by using the object ID for example?

```
class Example
end

ex1 = Example.new

ex1.object_id
  > 70184576592420

ex2 = ex1
```

Perhaps it would look something like this:

```
obj_id(70184576592420).var_names
  > [ex1, ex2]
```

Comment: What do you want this for? What would you expect to see if it's referenced in an array or hash?

Answer (score 4):

I would extend @sagarpandya82 answer:

```
local_variables.select do |e| 
  binding.local_variable_get(e).object_id == 70184576592420
end
#=> [:ex2, :ex1]
```

Just `local_variables` returns a list of *all* local variables.